# Asyncio show result for each task result immediately once after is completed

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently i use `asyncio.wait(*tasks)` for all tasks to be completed and then results are shown for each task. Nevertheless i would like to show result from each task when specific task is completed. Is there an option for that?

Comment: How do you "show" the result right now? Are you using ``print(await asyncio.wait(*tasks)``? For your desired usage, do you still want to get a list of results in addition to "showing" each?

Comment: some tasks may get `callback` which is executed after end of task - and you can use function's name which will display result.

Comment: [asyncio.Future.add_done_callback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future.add_done_callback)

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions

1. display it directly in `task` - but this may not be interesting for you.
2. assign `callback` function which will be executed when `task` is finished

   ```
   task.add_done_callback(show_result)
   ```

---

Minimal working example

```
import asyncio
import random


def show_result(task):
    """callback"""
    number, time = task.result()
    print(f'callback: number: {number} time: {time}')
    

async def task(number, time):
    print(f'start : number: {number} time: {time}')
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    print(f'end   : number: {number} time: {time}')
    return number,time


async def main():
    # random times for sleep

    times = list(range(1, 6))
    random.shuffle(times)
    
    # create tasks with callbacks

    tasks = []
    
    for number, time in enumerate(times):
        t = asyncio.create_task(task(number, time))
        t.add_done_callback(show_result)
        tasks.append(t)

    print('--- during wait ---')
        
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)
    
    print('--- after wait ---')
    
    # display results also after all tasks
    for t in tasks:
        #print('result:', t.result())
        show_result(t)
        
asyncio.run(main())
```

Result:

```
--- during wait ---
start : number: 0 time: 5
start : number: 1 time: 4
start : number: 2 time: 2
start : number: 3 time: 3
start : number: 4 time: 1
end   : number: 4 time: 1
callback: number: 4 time: 1
end   : number: 2 time: 2
callback: number: 2 time: 2
end   : number: 3 time: 3
callback: number: 3 time: 3
end   : number: 1 time: 4
callback: number: 1 time: 4
end   : number: 0 time: 5
callback: number: 0 time: 5
--- after wait ---
callback: number: 0 time: 5
callback: number: 1 time: 4
callback: number: 2 time: 2
callback: number: 3 time: 3
callback: number: 4 time: 1
```